# Texture Problem, Multiple Textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm using cycles render. The problem is the emission plate (no matter what size) won't hit some areas.

I'm a beginner in Blender, I started a week ago.

Picture:
[image]

My scene looks like this:
[image: The emission on the plates is 2]

Can anyone help be diagnose this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please show your materials for the dark areas.  Nodes might be easiest

Comment: It looks like the materials for the black areas don't have anything plugged into the *material output* node.

Comment: This is what was in the materials tab http://prntscr.com/8broqm

Comment: What are material outpout nodes?

Comment: Did you uv unwrap the mesh??

Comment: Look in the node editor.

Comment: ^ I don't think so. All I did was RMB on one of the legs, went to materials, added a material, changed the color to image texture, selected which image I wanted and that's pretty much it.

Comment: ^ I did that for everything

Comment: I think I may have found the problem, but here it is http://prntscr.com/8brxph

Comment: if you need a uv unwrapping video tutorial in the future here is a link to one ......     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger it's already unwrapped.

Comment: For me it renders fine

Comment: I found the problem! I had two textures, very simmilar, but the one I was using had a large black spot, instead of the correct one. Ii'm so sorry to everyone for doing such a silly mistake :P Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we've all done that at one point or another. :)

Comment: I'm a noob with blender, it's like my second time using it, lol!

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer and accept it to take this off the unanswered list.